# Could anyone guide me to develop with qrcode in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, barcode, qr-code, zxing

I am developing my camera application that can decoded the qrcode in real time of camera on.

When I open the camera,  I set the timer about every 3 seconds interval to capture picture on the screen with Display.screenshot(); method and then decoded it with zxing library while camera is on.   Sometimes, it can capture the qrcode and successful decoded, but otherwise it hard to decoded the picture.  I think the problem is about camera. I can not use auto focus with the camera, so the capture picture is gloomy.  I want to know how to use auto focus with the camera.

- My application implement on OS version 5.0 and upper version.

Could anyone help me or suggestion about new solution ?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try BBBarcodeLib available for download here: http://aliirawan-wen.blogspot.com/2011/05/barcode-scanner-for-blackberry-os-50.html.

Note that for OS6 devices you can use the built in BlackBerry barcode scanning library (built on Google ZXing).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is likely that 3 second pause. You should be decoding frames as fast as you can, which should be many times per second. This will get you a successful scan much faster.

You can and should integrate the latest zxing library instead of using that built into RIM's OS if you can, as it has small improvements that will be helpful.